# jQuery Validation plugin with two submit buttons?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have one form with around 50 fields and two submit buttons, "SAVE" and "SAVE & SUBMIT".
If the user clicks "SAVE", then validate only some values, eg. field1, field2. When user clicks "SAVE & SUBMIT" button, it should validate all 50 fields and submit.

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field3" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field4" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="button1" value="Save" />
    <input type="submit" id="button2" value="Submit" />
</form>


$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#button1').click(function(){          
        $("#myform").validate({             
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true                         
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true                        
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo    
                alert("data saved");
            }
        });
    }); 

    $('#button2').click(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({             
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true                          
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true                           
                },
                field3: {
                    required: true                         
                },
                field4: {
                    required: true                          
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert("data submited");
            }
        });
    });

});
```

I have created jsfiddle for this: [example test](http://jsfiddle.net/3vjr5/2/)

Comment: What's your question? Please post your code here, not just as a fiddle link.

Comment: `validate` is designed to be applied once to a form. Whichever button you press first is setting the validation from then onwards. You would need to figure out how to strip existing validation from all fields before applying `validate` again.

Comment: @Barmar as i said i have 50 fields it i post all my code it will be very log question. there is no point to down voting this question.
all the test i have done on jsfiddle.

Comment: Which `validate` are you using (download page please)? Some validation plugins allow you to add and remove rules dynamically (but I have a feeling yours is not one of those).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, he's using [the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org) based on the OP stating, _"the jQuery Validation plugin"_, his `.validate()` code, and the [tag:jquery-validate] tag.  And yes, it allows dynamic rule changes.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your code...

```
$('#button1').click(function(){             
    $("#myform").validate({
        ....
    });             
}); 

$('#button2').click(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        ....
    });
});
```

You absolutely **cannot** do this:

1)  You cannot call the `.validate()` method more than once on the same `form`.  Any subsequent calls are always ignored.

2)  You should not put the `.validate()` method inside of a `click` handler.  The `.validate()` method is the *initialization* method of the plugin and only gets called *once* within a DOM ready event handler.  After proper *initialization*, the submit button click is captured automatically by the plugin.

---

**HTML Markup and Click Handlers**:

This plugin also automatically captures the click of any `input type="submit"` and `button type="submit"` elements and initiates validation/submission.

So if you need to control what happens for two different buttons, then you first need to change your buttons into `input type="button"` or `button type="button"` elements.

Then you can use `click()` handlers to dynamically change the rules with the `.rules()` methods as per which button was clicked.  See [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) documentation.

Use `.submit()` to programmatically submit.  In other words, this will trigger a validation test and attempt to submit the form IF valid... same as if you had a `submit` button.

Use [`.valid()`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) to programmatically test the form.  In other words, this will trigger a validation test but will NOT submit the form IF valid.

---

**Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({  // initialize the plugin on your form
        // options, rules and/or callbacks
    });

    //  IMPORTANT:  buttons are NOT type="submit"

    $('#button1').on('click', function(){  // capture the click           
        $('#myfield').rules('add', {  // dynamically declare the rules
            required: true,
            email: true
        });
        $('#myOtherField').rules('remove'); // remove the other rules.
        // another '.rules()' call, etc.
        $('#myform').valid();  // trigger the validation & do NOT submit        
    }); 

    $('#button2').on('click', function(){  // capture the click
        $('#myOtherField').rules('add', {  // dynamically declare the rules
            required: true,
            digits: true
        });
        $('#myfield').rules('remove'); // remove the other rules.
        // another '.rules()' call, etc.
        $('#myform').submit();  // trigger the validation & submit     
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Kt93M/**

The demo is simply [your original jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vjr5/2/) with these principles applied.

Comment: thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation on usage of .validate()

Comment: An alternative: you CAN use submit buttons, e.g., so that the server knows which one was clicked. This is also a more declarative solution: use jQuery.validator.addClassRules(), add or remove a certain class in response to clicks. Here's @Sparky 's fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/s6v45gka/1

Comment: @full.stack.ex, It does not matter if you manipulate classes or use the `.rules()` method... in your example, both buttons are submitting the form after validation.  However, the OP did NOT want to submit with both buttons.

Comment: @full.stack.ex, [also, you can simply add/remove the `required` class; you do not need to use the `.addClassRules()` method at all](http://jsfiddle.net/s6v45gka/2/).  The `.addClassRules()` method is for constructing *compound* rules; the standard rules such as `required` can already be assigned by class all by themselves.

Comment: @Sparky , you are right. Your solution is 100% correct. We've just used your answer and added the "declarative" approach to submit with 2 buttons. Thought someone might need the same. Thank you!

Comment: @full.stack.ex, ok, I see.  Check out my very last comment; it might help you make it more efficient.

Comment: @Sparky , thank you again for your findings. In fact, we do have compound rules. I get it: it may be too far from the original question. You are right, in the simplest case, the required class would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use the same validation, maybe you should this code:

Insert an hidden action, to say the validation the method to use after we click the button

```
<input type="hidden" id="action" name="action">
```

Then in your submit Handler:

```
submitHandler: function (form, event) {
    var action = $("#formPagoContratista #action").val();
    if (action === "action_1") {
        firstFunction();
    }else if (action === "action_2") {
        secondFunction();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the below two buttons:

```
<div class="form-group text-right my-5 ">
  <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-bg col-sm-2 form-control" value="Save">
```

You can validate and submit based on the two buttons: 
Save sends with ajax and no reload.  Next button saves and redirects to next page.

```
$('form').validate({
            submitHandler: function(form, e) {
              var button = $(":focus", this);

              var name = button.context.submitButton.defaultValue;
              console.log(name);
              if(name == "Save"){
                $(form).ajaxSubmit();
              }else{
                form.submit();
              }
            }
          });
```

checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423083/1004799